# Как программно выполнить событие клика DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

У меня такая проблема, мне нужно когда я вхожу на форму программно кликнуть по первой строке `DataGridView`. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: Кликнуть или выбирать?

Comment: именно кликнуть. как выделить я знаю, но это мне не подходит

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так (клик по ячейке `[0, 0]`):

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     dataGridView1_CellClick(this, new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(0, 0));
}

private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //Ваш код
}
```

Comment: 'public Form22()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1_CellClick(this, new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(0, 0));
            
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        } '
ошибку выдает на эту строчку " textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();"

Comment: @liorbraiz, что именно за ошибка?

Comment: Необработанное исключение типа "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException" в mscorlib.dll

Дополнительные сведения: Индекс за пределами диапазона. Индекс должен быть положительным числом, а его размер не должен превышать размер коллекции.

Comment: @liorbraiz, здесь создается форма с `dataGridView` с не инициализированными значениями. Вы же пытаетесь эти значения загнать в текстбоксы. Какая основная идея, что Вы хотите сделать в программе?

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать так не лучщий но вариант

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Selected = true;
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "00";
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = "01";
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = "02";
        dataGridView1.Click += DataGridView1_Click;
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       DataGridView1_Click(sender, e);
    }

    private void DataGridView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value);
        listBox1.Items.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value);
        listBox1.Items.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value);
    }
```

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException" в mscorlib.dll

Это означает что у вас во время работы события `datagridview` не инициализирована.
То есть `dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0]=null` а вы пытаетесь еще и значение получить.